# Create PDF/A3 document with Open Libraries

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdfa, openpdf

I want to create a PDF/A3 document with Java. I already came across iText5 and was able to do so. But due to its AGPL license, I can't use it in commercial code. I was looking for it's alternatives and found Apache PDFBox and OpenPDF, but couldn't find any sample code to begin with.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can absolutely use iText in a commercial code. You just need to get a commercial license.

Comment: You could start with the `CreatePDFA.java` example and change the `id.setPart(1);` to `id.setPart(3);` and see whether VeraPDF considers this to be valid.

Comment: https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/issues/110